# I couldn't show article on view rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm beginner of programming and doing the project on rails.
I'm having a problem that I can't show the data on view.
The codes are listed bellow.

```
#routes.rb

  scope module: :mobile do
    scope module: :home do
      get "/", action: :index
```

-

```
#index.html.slim

  - if @pickup_links.present?
      .user-posts-area
        .inner-headline
          h2 Pickup Link
          h3 ピックアップリンク
        .top-user-posts
      - pl = @pickup_links  
          a.post href=pl.page_path
            img.lazy data-original=pl.picture
            .post-descs
              h3 = pl.title_or_notitle
              h4 = pl.name_or_no_name
              .date-area
                .right-date = pl.created_at.to_s(:md_dot_en)
```

-

```
#home_controller.rb

def index
 @pickup_links = PickupLink.limit(1)
end
```

I tested "@pickup_links = PickupLink.limit(1)" on terminal and could get the data from the database.
Please someone give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with "slim" but it looks like "HAML". So my guess is that your line

```
- pl = @pickup_links
```

is not a block, so all following line should not be nested.

Another matter (I know this is only a test project but) why don't you do

```
# why link**s**
@pickup_links = PickupLink.first
```

then you would only test like this

```
- if @pickup_links
```

and you would not need to set

```
-pl = @pickup_links
```

but just use @pickup_links. "pl" btw is still a relation of PickupLink and has none of the methods you are calling